# SSIS: how to read the result of a stored procedure into a global variable or something useful

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, bids

I have a stored procedure i want to run which will return  a 0 or a 1.  I would like to store that value in a ssis variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. use a dataflow task
2. define the variable using the "variable" tab on the left hand side (next to the toolbox tab)
3. use the "exectute sql task"
4. in the properties of the sql task setup a result set

Comment: And you can set the scope of those variables as appropriate, too.